# How can I create rows without an underlying table in IBM DB2 SQL?

Tags: db2

In T-SQL, I can execute the following:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS n) AS t;
```

In IBM DB2 SQL, this fails with:

> [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0199 - Keyword
>   UNION not expected. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.

A `SELECT` statement seems to require a `FROM` clause. Indeed, a reductive SQL statement such as:

```
SELECT 1 AS n
```

Also errors with:

> [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token
>    was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.

There is an [UNNEST function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0055064.html) which can create rows from an array, but it seems the array must already be represented by something like a variable or parameter.

I understand I could work around this by doing a `SELECT` from an arbitrary table with an impossible criterion such as 1 = 0, but that seems to be a silly requirement.

So how can I construct rows without an underlying table?

(keywords: tally table; derived table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB2 for i5 V5R4 [does not support the `VALUES` statement](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/systemi/v5r4/en_US/rbafzmst.pdf) as a table reference, so examples provided in another answer won't work in that version. However, all versions of DB2 offer a single row pseudo-table `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`, which can be used to generate rows:

```
SELECT 1 AS n FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS n FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Answer (score 4):

Platform and version are important when asking about Db2...

In this case it appears you're running Db2 for IBM i (iSeries, AS/400)

What you are looking for is known in the SQL standards as ***table value constructor*** which looks like `VALUES (<row1>),(<row2>),(...)`

On Db2 for i (and LUW I believe) the following are a couple of ways...

```
-- Using a Common Table Expression (CTE)
WITH X(foo, bar, baz) AS (
VALUES (0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)
) SELECT * FROM X;


-- Using a Nested Table Expression (NTE)
SELECT * FROM TABLE (
VALUES (0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)
) X(foo, bar, baz);
```

However, you appear to be using an older version of Db2 for i (v5?)  I don't recall if that version supports table value constructors...